# Is it a bad idea to make a count the primary key?

Tags: sql, database-design, primary-key

Just thinking about database design issues. Suppose i have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE LEGACYD.CV_PLSQL_COUNT 
(
    RUN_DTTM  DATE NOT NULL,
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR (80) NOT NULL,
    COUNT Number(50) PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Is that a bad idea - to make the COUNT  a PRIMARY KEY ? Generally, how should I make the decision of what is a primry key?

Comment: What is your purpose?Why not use a sequence?

Comment: @Mihai - Hmm, why is sequence better?

Comment: Is this definition even legal in your database? `COUNT` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: I'm using Oracle  let me see

Comment: Fundamentally you have to know what business rules (specifically rules about uniqueness) that you want to enforce in your database. Beyond that, some sensible criteria for selecting a keys are: Simplicity, Familiarity and Stability. We can't choose for you because we don't know about the business domain you are modelling or whether your "count" is a simple, familiar and stable identifier.

Comment: What is COUNT? The number of rows that already existed in the table before you inserted the given row? If yes, then this number is not well defined in a _concurrent_ environment (where transactions can insert/delete rows in parallel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that a bad idea - to make the COUNT a PRIMARY KEY ? Generally, how should I make the decision of what is a primry key?

Candidate keys are based on functional dependencies. A primary key is one of the candidate keys. There's no formal way to look at a set of candidate keys and say, "*This one* must be the primary key." That decision is based on practical matters, not on formal logic.

Your table structure tells us these things.

- COUNT is unique. No matter how many rows this table has, you'll never find two rows that have the same value for COUNT.
- COUNT determines TABLE_NAME. That is, given a value for COUNT, we will forever find one and only one value for TABLE_NAME.
- TABLE_NAME is not unique. We expect to find several rows that have the same value for TABLE_NAME.
- COUNT determines RUN_DTTM. That is, given a value for COUNT, we will forever find one and only one value for RUN_DTTM.
- RUN_DTTM is not unique. We expect to find several rows that have the same value for RUN_DTTM.
- The combination of TABLE_NAME and RUN_DTTM is not unique. We expect to find several rows that have the same values for TABLE_NAME and RUN_DTTM in a single row.
- There are no other determinants. That means that given a value for TABLE_NAME, we'll find multiple unrelated values for COUNT and RUN_DTTM. Likewise, if we're given a value for RUN_DTTM, or values for the pair of columns {TABLE_NAME, RUN_DTTM}.

If all those things are true, then COUNT might be a good primary key. But I doubt that all those things are true.

Based only on the column names--a risky way to proceed--I think it's far more likely that the only candidate key is {TABLE_NAME, RUN_DTTM}.  I think it's also likely that either RUN_DTTM is misnamed, or RUN_DTTM has the wrong data type. If it's a date, you probably meant to name it RUN_DT; if it's a timestamp, the data type should be TIMESTAMP.